If you commit on GitHub by linking it with BaekjoonHub, the commit will not be made with today’s date
When you connect to Baekjoon Hub, solve a problem in Programmers or Baekjoon, and commit, the commit is made with yesterday's date, not today's date.
This has been happening for a while. Is there another way?
How can I update the commit to today's date?

Are you sure it's not just updating with the current date and time in UTC?

Yes, after some time, it will be uploaded as a commit with today's date and time.
